# Why is my RVM configuration messed up?

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I think I screwed up my development environment the other day and I can't figure out how to get RVM working again.

I cleaned up my startup files for my shell and consolidated my `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, and `.bashrc` files into a single `.bash_profile` in my user directory.

Ever since I did this, my RVM environment has been screwed up. Now, when I do a `which rails` and `which ruby`, my system is now referencing my `/usr/local/bin` directory instead of my `~/.rvm/bin` like it used to.

Here are the first two lines of my `.bash_profile` config:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin:$PATH"
```

I'm not a UNIX guru and I fear that I'm missing a certain variable name in my "`$PATH`" declaration. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the RVM line at the end of your .profile and ensure that there are no `return` statement in it.

See the RVM installation [documentation](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/).

Especially :

> Ensure that RVM is sourced after any path settings as RVM and manipulates the path. If you don't do this, RVM may not work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm not 100% sure it worked. Now I'm getting an error with some conflicting ruby versions: 


[tdlog (master)]$ rails server
/Users/farmerluc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin10.0.0]

Abort trap

Comment: Marked your answer as the accepted answer. I realize that I posted a follow up of another problem. Once I re-configured my 'rvm use 1.9.2@rails3tutorial --default', my `which rails` now returns the correct path. Thanks for your help. :)